# Sinusoids in python

Tags: python

Write the function `sinusoid(a, w, n)` that will return a list of ordered pairs representing n cycles of a sinusoid with amplitude a and frequency w. Each cycle should contain 180 ordered pairs.

So far I have:

```
def sinusoid(a,w,n):
    return [a*sin(x) for x in range 180]
```

Comment: Is this homework? If show you should tag it as such.

Comment: That function doesn't return a list of ordered pairs!

Comment: You don't have to create a different name each time. This is better worded though. http://stackoverflow.com/users/645398/bailey

Comment: What do mathemeticians get if they sit on a Trigonometry book for too long?

Comment: Try simplifying the problem. First, solve it for amplitude 1, one cycle, frequency of 1 cycle every 2*pi. Once you get that working, expand on it.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider the actual functional form of a sinusoidal wave and how the frequency comes into the equation. (Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave).

Not sure what is meant exactly by 'ordered pairs', but I would assume it means the x,y pairs. Currently you're only returning a list of single values. Also you might want to take a look at the documentation for Python's `sin` function.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, we know this is a homework assignment and we're not going to do it for you. However, I'll give you a couple hints.

The instructions:

Write the function `sinusoid(a, w, n)` that will return a list of ordered pairs representing n cycles of a sinusoid with amplitude a and frequency w. Each cycle should contain 180 ordered pairs.

... translated into a bullet list of requirements:

- Write a function
- ... named `sinusoid()`
- ... taking three arguments: `a`, `w`, and `n`
- returning a list
- ... of n cycles(?)
- ... (each consisting of?) 180 "ordered pairs"

The example you've given does define a function, by the correct name, and taking the correct number of arguments.  That's a start (not much of one, frankly, but it's something).

The obvious failings are that it doesn't use two of the arguments that are required and it doesn't return pairs of anything.  It seems that it would return 180 numbers which are based on the argument supplied to its first parameter.

Surely you can do a bit better than that.

Let's start with a stub:

```
def sinusoid(a, w, n):
    '''Return n cycles of the sinusoid for a given amplitude and frequence
       where each cycle consists of 180 ordered pairs
    '''
    results = list()
    # do stuff here
    return results
```

That's a function, takes three arguments and returns a list.  Now for that list to contain anything before we return it we'll have to append some things to it ... and the instructions tell us how many things it should return (`n` times 180) and what sorts of things they should be (ordered pairs).

That sounds quite a bit like we'll need a loop (for `n`) and another (for 180). Hmmm ...

That might look like:

```
for each_cycle in range(n):
    for each_pair in range(180):
        # do something here
        results.append(something) # where something is a tuple ... an "ordered pair"
```

... or it might look like:

```
for each_cycle in range(n):
    this_cycle = list()
    for each_pair in range(180):
        this_cycle.append(something)
    results.extend(this_cycle)
```

... or it might even look like:

```
for each_pair in range(n*180):
    results.append(something)
```

... though, frankly, that seems unlikely.  (If you try flattening the inner loop to the outer loop in this way you might find that you're having to use modulo arithmetic to get n back out for some other intermediate computational purposes).

I have no idea what the instructor is actually asking for.  It seems likely that the `math.sin()` function will be involved and I guess "ordered pairs" might be co-ordinates mapped to some sort of graphics subsystem and suitable for plotting a graph.  I guess 180 of these to show the sinusoid wave through a full range of its values.  Maybe you're supposed to multiply something by the amplitude and/or divide something else by the frequency and maybe  you're supposed to even add something for each cycle ... some sort of offset to keep the plot moving towards the right or something.

But it seems like you might start with that stub of a function definition and try pasting in one or another of these loop bodies and then figuring out how to actually return meaningful values in the parts where I've used "something" as a placeholder.

Going with the assumption that these "ordered pairs" are co-ordinates, for plotting, then it seems likely that each of the things you append to your results should be of the form `(x,y)` where `x` is monotonically increasing (fancy way of saying it keeps going up, never goes down) and might even always be the `range(0,n*180)` and `y` is probably `math.sin()` of something involved `a` and `w` ... but that's just speculation on my part.